# Data passing from parent component to the child component with reactjs and type script with the React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the following component I have to pass the profile information from the Parent component to the child component though the children property. I want to pass the "profile" object to the child components which were wrapped with the "ProfileLayout". I was able to wrap the data with the "React.cloneElement" but not sure how to access those properties from the child component. I tried to access those simply with "children.profile" but it seems not working.

In "routes.tsx"

```
<ProfileLayout>
        <Route path="/profile/change-password" component={ChangePassword} />
        <Route path="/profile/my-profile" component={MyProfile} />
</ProfileLayout>
```

In "ProfileLayout.tsx"

```
interface AppProps {
    children: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element;
}

const ProfileLayout: FunctionComponent<AppProps> = ({ children }:  AppProps) => {

    const [profile, setProfile] = useState({ firstName: "", lastName: "", profilePictureURL: "", website: "", email: "" });

    useEffect(() => {
        const myProfile = async() => {
            const profileResponse = await XXXXXXXXX.GetProfile();
            setProfile(profileResponse);
        };
        myProfile();
    }, []);

    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    const childsSet = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => React.cloneElement(child, {
            index,
            profile
        }));

    return (
        <FullScreen>
            <div className="container my__profile--container">
                <Row>
                    <Col span={18} push={6}>
                        <h1>{pathname.indexOf("my-profile") > -1 ? "Profile Details" : "Change Password"}</h1>
                        <Card className="profile__layout--card--container">
                            {childsSet}
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                    <ProfileLeftMenu myprofile={profile} />
                </Row>
            </div>
        </FullScreen>
    );
};
```

If someone can help with this scenario that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using composed component style, your props are passed on to the Route component but it doesn't then forward it to the rendered component.

What you can instead do is adopt a render prop approach and forward it to the component

```
<ProfileLayout>
   {(props) => (
      <>
        <Route path="/profile/change-password" render={(routeProps) => <ChangePassword {...props} {...routeProps} />} />
        <Route path="/profile/my-profile" render={(routeProps) => <MyProfile {...props} {...routeProps} />} />
      </>
   )}
</ProfileLayout>
```

---

```
interface Profile {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   profilePictureURL: string;
   website: string;
   email: string;
}
interface AppProps {
    children: ({ profile:  Profile }) => ReactNode;
}

const ProfileLayout: FunctionComponent<AppProps> = ({ children }:  AppProps) => {

    const [profile, setProfile] = useState<Profile>({ firstName: "", lastName: "", profilePictureURL: "", website: "", email: "" });

    useEffect(() => {
        const myProfile = async() => {
            const profileResponse = await XXXXXXXXX.GetProfile();
            setProfile(profileResponse);
        };
        myProfile();
    }, []);

    const { pathname } = useLocation();


    return (
        <FullScreen>
            <div className="container my__profile--container">
                <Row>
                    <Col span={18} push={6}>
                        <h1>{pathname.indexOf("my-profile") > -1 ? "Profile Details" : "Change Password"}</h1>
                        <Card className="profile__layout--card--container">
                            {props.children({profile})}
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                    <ProfileLeftMenu myprofile={profile} />
                </Row>
            </div>
        </FullScreen>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. But I still didn't get it and If I try to put the first stuff to the routes file by replacing the previous piece of code then I am getting bunch of typescript errors. Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Updated the answer by changing children Type for ProfileLayout component

Comment: Glad to have helped